# In search of fastest way of finding the words/strings in large text file

Tags: php

I have written this code which searches for a particular word in a very large file. The file is about 5GB and with 50+ million lines. The code works fine but I believe there is a way to improve it. Unfortunately, database isn't an option. Must work with files at this point.

The code:

```
$count = 0;
$word = "dealersVA";

function getLines($file) {
    $f = fopen($file, 'r') or 
            die("Unable to open file!");
    try {
        while (($line = fgets($f, 4096)) !== false) {
            yield $line;    
        }
    } finally {
        fclose($f);
    }
} 

foreach (getLines("dealers.txt") as $n => $line) {

    if (str_starts_with($line, $word) ) {
        $line = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, "."));
        $count++;
    }       
}
```

The file content is as follows

```
dealersVA
Magic
NorthShoreIE
VA
BankO
dealersVA
...
//so on
```

For example - when I search for `dealersVA` the script goes line by line till the end and checks how many times `dealersVA` is in the file. The current file has 59 million lines and the `dealersVA` is 300 times in it. This takes about 30 seconds.

Is there somehow a way to get a bit faster the results? I was thinking probably to not search for the whole word but maybe for the first char, then first+second, then first+second+third. Or get it in chunks or some algorithm.

Comment: Is there a good reason for `dealersVA` being in the file 300 times? my thoughts are if there is no good reason, you should tidy the file and then your search would be quicker

Comment: Otherwise, if you have to use a flat file and not a database, welcome to slowly slowly! I am actually quite impressed with processing 59 million lines in a text file in 30 seconds

Comment: Data is pulled from a number of APIs and stored in this file. The search word can be anything not only `dealersVA`.

Comment: Actually, at some point, they were nearly 300 million, and took around a minute for a search.

Comment: If this search is your primary function for this file, I would work on the code that adds data to it. Obviously to speed those up someone has decided duplicated dont matter, and maybe they were wrong.

Comment: If you assume all lines are duplicated 300'ish times, you could reduce the size of this file down to around 2 million by dropping duplicates

Comment: I understand what you're trying to suggest but this is the main purpose of it. It gathers information from around 50 APIs. Then I can search for given words and what amount they are appearing for later references. Some words are appearing 1 time, sometimes the word that I search isn't presented at all.

Comment: Out of interest, why is a database out of the question

Comment: Maybe in the near feature, it will go into the database but at this point is decided to not go. (not by me unfortunately and can't change minds so far). Just trying to make it a bit faster.